# Is there a simple way to rank on multiple criteria that preserves ties in R?

Tags: r

When a single criterion is well ordered, the rank function returns the obvious thing:

```
rank(c(2,4,1,3,5))
[1] 2 4 1 3 5
```

When a single criterion has ties, the rank function (by default) assigns average ranks to the ties:

```
rank(c(2,4,1,1,5))
[1] 3.0 4.0 1.5 1.5 5.0
```

The rank function doesn't let you sort on multiple criteria, so you have to use something else.  One way to do it is by using match and order.  For a single criterion without ties the results are the same:

```
rank(c(2,4,1,3,5))
[1] 2 4 1 3 5

match(1:5, order(c(2,4,1,3,5)))
[1] 2 4 1 3 5
```

For a single criterion with ties, however, the results differ:

```
rank(c(2,4,1,4,5))
[1] 2.0 3.5 1.0 3.5 5.0

match(1:5, order(c(2,4,1,4,5)))
[1] 2 3 1 4 5
```

The ties are broken in such a way that the tied elements have their original order preserved rather than being assigned equal ranks.  This feature generalizes, obviously, when you sort on multiple criteria:

```
match(1:5, order(c(2,4,1,4,5),c(10,11,12,11,13)))
[1] 2 3 1 4 5
```

Finally, the question:  Is there a simple, or built-in, way of computing rank using multiple criteria that preserves ties?  I've written a function to do it, but it's ugly and seems ridiculously complicated for such a basic functionality...

Comment: What do you want the ranks to be for the last example?

Comment: `2.0 3.5 1.0 3.5 5.0` is the desired result.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`interaction` does what you need:

```
> rank(interaction(c(2,4,1,4,5),c(10,11,12,11,13), lex.order=TRUE))
[1] 2.0 3.5 1.0 3.5 5.0
```

Here is what is happening.

`interaction` expects factors, so the vectors are coerced.  Doing so produces the order in the factor levels as indicated by `sort.list`, which for `numeric` is numerically nondecreasing order.
Then to combine the two factors, the interaction creates factor levels by varying the second argument fastest (because `lex.order=TRUE`).  Thus ties in the first vector are resolved by the value in the second vector (if possible).
Finally, `rank` coerces the resulting factor to `numeric`.

What is actually ranked:

```
> as.numeric(interaction(c(2,4,1,4,5),c(10,11,12,11,13), lex.order=TRUE))
[1]  5 10  3 10 16
```

You will save some memory if you supply the option `drop=TRUE` to `interaction`.  This will change the ranked numeric values, but not their order, so the final result is the same.

Comment: I haven't checked, but does `lex.order` do anything weird if there is input where numerical rather than lexical order is desired, e.g. `c(10,2,12,2,13)` ... ?

Comment: `rank` is coercing the result of `interaction` to numeric, so no.  `lex.order` does not mean to sort alphabetically.