# Is there an easy way to rank values in R using two criteria (the second one being for the ties)?

Tags: r, sorting, criteria, rank

I have been wondering whether there is a simple way of ranking values in R with two criteria: one for the main ranking and the other to rank the ties.

For instance, suppose we have the following sets of number:

```
a <- c(9,13,6,3,7,1,13)
b <- c(1,4,3,6,5,7,2)
```

Now, suppose we want to rank `a` using the information in `b` to handle the ties in `rank(a)`, so we end up having the following:

```
> 5 7 3 2 4 1 6
```

Is there an easy way to get that in R? The options in `rank` to deal with ties are of no help for that.

PS: there is a similar question on `rank` and ties already, but it's not a duplicate since it's not really asking the same thing despite its title suggesting so: [Is there a simple way to rank on multiple criteria that preserves ties in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103812/is-there-a-simple-way-to-rank-on-multiple-criteria-that-preserves-ties-in-r)

Comment: A work-around could be to add a very small value proportional to `b`, for instance: `rank(a+b*sqrt(.Machine$double.eps))`. Of course this just works if the values in `a` are scattered enough to not be shuffled by the term added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all ties are actually broken:

```
order(order(a, b))
#[1] 5 7 3 2 4 1 6
```

There are probably more efficient alternatives.

Comment: This is much better than my work-around. Guess it's also pretty efficient.

Comment: @nicola I don't like that it orders twice. I think the first call to `order` might even produce the result internally as an intermediate step (I didn't look at the source).

Comment: @Roland that is *very* simple, in a good way! Thanks. So, I agree that it's probably more efficient to implement a custom `order` command since it probably does that already in its functioning. But so far, it seems that performance-wise that's acceptable for my case. Only thing is: by all broken ties you mean the case when all ties do not tie again in `b`?

Comment: If `b` doesn't break all ties, the remaining ties will be broken by the "first" rule.